# Get notified of Build or Release that failed

Tags: azure-devops, azure-pipelines

I have integrated Azure pipelines with out team slack channel which is nice, it tells us when a build completes and release deploys.  The really bad thing about it though is is doesn't report when a build or release failed which is arguably more important information.

I went into settings to try to see if there is any event for it but it seems the answer is no.  Also I looked to see if it can be done with something else like Zapier but I couldn't see how.

How can I configure pipelines so our team is all notified of a broken build or failed release?

Comment: Don’t you ever try with service hook to connect to Slack?

Comment: How do you integrate now the success deploys? (which settings you looked?)

Comment: I followed this guide https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/integrations/slack?view=azure-devops

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As Guerrilla said, you should use the official application to integrate Slack into Azure DevOps.
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/integrations/slack?view=azure-devops

I recommend to use `/azpipelines subscribe` command to create new subscriptions (notifications for channels). The Slack UI provides better way to define what kind of notifications you will receive.

[image: azpipelines subscribe command gives UI to define notifications]

This is how it looks in Slack
[image: Failed build in Slack]

The other way to do it is to use direct command `/azpipelines subscribe https://dev.azure.com/myorg/myproject/_build?definitionId=123`, but it doesn't give an option to define when notifications are sent.

Comment: That is what I did, I mentioned it in comment.  If you read the documentation you linked to you will see there is no build failed or release failed event.

Comment: I added image which shows that you can subscribe to only failed builds.

Comment: Ahhh, I didn't realise there was status option.  Thankyou

Comment: Yeah the default is kind of odd that it doesn't add notifications for failed builds and you need to manually define it for every build you need it.

Comment: Unfortunately not possible to filter by branch, eg don't spam a channel if my PR build fails.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `service hook` to get the notification of build failed and release failed event. Here is the notification I received in Slack Channel .

[image]

(1) First, open your Slack Channel and add `Visual Studio Team Services` into your channel.

[image]

After you add it, you will see one page which teach you how to create service hook in Azure DevOps. Do not close this page, because while you create service hook in Azure DevOps, you will need the information showed below. Copy this webhook URL.

[image]

(2) Open Azure DevOps, **Project setting** -> **Service hook**, add service hook and select **Slack**. For getting build failed notification, select the event in Trigger tab as shown below.

[image]

(3) After step 2, click **Next**. In Action tab, paste the Slack webhook URL which showed in step1.

(4) Finish it. And run build pipeline, if it failed, you will get the notification in Slack Channel. From this notification, you can know much details about this failed build.

For failed release notification, you can refer my setting showed below.
[image]

Here is the [doc](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/service-hooks/services/slack?view=azure-devops&viewFallbackFrom=vsts) about this Slack service hook. You can refer it to get more details.